# How to get CPU, Memory and Network usage of a process(thread) in windows from command prompt(without GUI)?

Tags: windows, command-line, wmic

I need to know how much a process like process.exe uses the CPU/Mem/Net of system from command prompt of windows. I tried several commands like "typeperf" and "wmic" but I can not do the desired. As an example bellow command can take every 1sec CPU usage of process.exe upto 10times, but what about Memory and Network usage of that process?

```
typeperf "\Process(process.exe)\% Processor Time" -si 1 -sc 10
```

And finally what about overall usage of these resources?

Comment: `typeperf -qx "\Memory"` will show you what can be monitored for memory.

Comment: @DavidPostill It seems these queries run on the whole system. What about special process(thread) (for example memory usage of an arbitrary process like process.exe)? what about Network usage? Thanks